# How to use the delta scale option to keyframe the scale of an object to 0 and vice versa

Tags: objects, transforms, scale

So I have an animation with a lot of different objects and I wanna make some dissapear (from normal scale to 0) and make others show up (from 0 to normal scale) during the animation. I don't really know how to make the current scale of the objects the "normal" scale.

 I already had a few issues with the scale resetting and losing my objects and stuff like that, so I would like to know how to work with this 0 scale properly. I already searched for some videos but those didn't help me that much. Thanks in advance!